# ExtJS find events handlers registered with an object

Tags: events, extjs, event-handling, typo3

I would like to find which event handlers are registered over an object (in my concrete case it's the pagetree in the TYPO3 CMS backend).

Is there a method to get all event handlers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply walk through its `events` property. Most of the members will be just `true`, but those actually representing attached events will be objects. Type something like:

```
var es = Ext.getCmp('my-tree-id').events;
for (var k in es) {
    if (Ext.isObject(es[k])) {
        console.log(es[k]);
    }
}
```

If your object is a Ext.dom.Element, you would check `Ext.cache['elementId'].events` instead.