# How to verify EMail using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, email, selenium, extjs

My EXTJS application has a page with EMail button and on clicking it creates a link to page contents and opens default email client with this link in body.

In the inspect DOM, the EMail button has just this.

```
<span id="basebutton-1358-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-basebutton-large">Email</span>
```

In the entire DOM, there is no 'mailTo'.

All I need to verify here is the link that is generated on click. I don't really concerned about whether it opens up any Email client or not.

Comment: We need more info, probably a javascript somewhere doing the work. Hard to say without a link

Comment: Exactly, its the javascript doing all the work against this element. On click it triggers a script and fires the mailTo with a content. Unfortunately I dont have a public link which I can share.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for events registered on "Email" button by the javascript. In that case refer similar question for [EXTJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039597/extjs-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object) and [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518421/jquery-find-events-handlers-registered-with-an-object)
The way you are trying to do validation should be part of unit testing not of black-box testing.

Comment: But is there any way this  kind of verification can be done using selenium and java script alone ?